# How to fix 'this.stickit() is not a function' error in Backbone.stickit

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-stickit

I am trying to use backbone.stickit together with Marionette but somehow it doesn't recognize the stickit function. I keep getting the error:

> this.stickit() is not a function

I am using versions **Backbone 1.3.3**, **Marionette 2.4.7** and **stickit 0.9.2**. I have tried older and newer versions of both Backbone and Marionette but it does not solve the issue. I call the `this.stickit()` function in the onRender, I also tried to use it in onShow but no luck there. I also have an onDestroy function where I use `this.unstickit()` and that does not give any errors. Does anyone have any ideas what causes this issue?

```
import { ItemView } from 'backbone.marionette';
import 'backbone.stickit';
import template from './test.html';

const TestView = ItemView.extend({

  template,

  bindings: {
    '#input-name': 'name',
    '#label-name': 'name'
  },

  onRender() {
    this.stickit();
  },

  onDestroy() {
    this.unstickit();
  }

});

export default TestView;
```

I have tried earlier versions of backbone and marionette but then I get another error about a 'radio' not found or something. I hope someone can help me solve the `this.stickit()` is not a function error.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that Stickit installs the latest version of backbone. So there were 2 versions of backbone installed (1.3.3 and 1.4.0). This had been solved by adding a resolution to package.json:

```
"resolutions": {
    "backbone.stickit/backbone":"1.3.3"
  }
```